# Ubuntu tells me I have packages to upgrade when I don't

Tags: 10.04, upgrade, aptitude

I have a server machine that I never log into the X display on, only via ssh.  Recently I logged in and it told me I had

```
12 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

I actually already knew that because I run munin on it and all my other servers.  So anyway, I did "sudo aptitude" and installed all the updates, then rebooted.  A few days later, munin told me I needed to upgrade another package, so I logged on, but the login message said:

```
12 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

I went into aptitude and installed the one update.  Ubuntu is still telling me I have 12 packages to update.  Munin tells I don't have any.  I tried `aptitude -d -y dist-upgrade` and `apt-get -d -y dist-upgrade` and both of them tell me there is nothing to install.  So why is the login information still telling me I have 12 packages to update?

Comment: Did you do `sudo aptitude update` again?  Just to make sure it updated ;)  Also, running `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` might help, you can use aptitude just like apt-get, with the command-line arguments... `aptitude` alone starts the interactive interface, which I personally know a good group of users dont use.

Comment: @Evil, it's not aptitude that's having the problem, it's whatever Ubuntu uses to report how many packages need to be upgraded.  aptitude installed the 12 package updates a few days ago.

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing the same issue on Ubuntu 10.10 now. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Yes, could you submit a bug on this? and link to this question.

Comment: On Trusty 14.04.3 LTS, running "sudo aptitude safe-upgrade" has removed these messages, when "sudo apt-get upgrade" didn't.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a [bug in initscripts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/659738), fixed in Natty, which copies the current state of `motd` to `/etc/motd.tail`. `motd` is dynamically generated whenever you boot but `motd.tail` is static (allowing a sysadmin to place some fixed information there for all users).

Deleting `motd.tail` will fix the issue temporarily but a better solution is to create an empty `motd.tail`. If the file doesn't exist then it may be created again (incorrectly) when `initscripts` is upgraded.

Create an empty `motd.tail` with

```
sudo touch /etc/motd.tail
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same problem in 12.04.2 LTS, and there is no `/etc/motd.tail` file; just `/etc/motd`, which contains the offending text. The timestamp ("System information as of...") is accurate, but the updateable package count is not.

Answer (score 6):

The problem appears to be the logic in  `/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available` which is deciding that there are is no reason to run `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable` based on timestamps on `/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available` and sources.list and a few other files.

I'm not sure what the actual bug is, but removing the cached file has at least reset it to 0 updates, although God only knows if it will show the correct number when there are updates available.

Answer (score 5):

I've recently answered a similar question on Serverfault:

#### [ubuntu server: SSH banner telling to update packages but nothing to update](https://serverfault.com/q/270094/51929)

That banner you're talking about is called MOTD (Message Of The Day). It appears to be [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pam/+bug/766827/comments/3) which can be work-arounded by deleting the `/etc/motd.tail` file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `/etc/motd.tail` contains the update messages. If yes, remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue on 10.04.2.

```
# aptitude install update-motd

Selecting previously deselected package update-motd.
(Reading database ... 36453 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking update-motd (from .../update-motd_3.5-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
 Removing any system startup links for /etc/init.d/update-motd ...
Setting up update-motd (3.5-0ubuntu1) ...
```

But there's no update-motd command line tool afterwords and I can't find anything about pam_motd.

Removing the `/etc/motd` made the message go away, but obviously the safe-upgrade should have already done that.

Answer (score 1):

On several systems I had seen incorrect reports of packages to be updated, but also 2 lines 'Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS' and 'Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS' even though I was on 10.04.2.

As Karl said, /etc/motd.tail contained the old text, and deleting it solved the problem for me perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.
The solution was to simply run motd update script with force flag:

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force
```

This has updated motd information and now shows 0 updates.