# How to install updates via command line?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates

When I log into my web server via SSH I see the information:

```
88 packages can be updated.
80 updates are security updates
```

I tried `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade` but each time I log in I still see the message about updates. How do I install them?

Comment: Did you try this first: sudo apt-get clean this should clean the cache.

Answer (score 1116):

Use this:

```bsh
sudo apt update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt upgrade       # Installs some updates; does not remove packages
sudo apt full-upgrade  # Installs updates; may also remove some packages, if needed
sudo apt autoremove    # Removes any old packages that are no longer needed
```

Documentation about each `apt` option can be found in the [the manpages for apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/en/man8/apt.8.html). These are also available by running `man apt` in your terminal.

Use of both `upgrade` and `full-upgrade` together is usually not needed, but it may help in some cases: see [Debian documentation about Upgrades from Debian 9](https://www.debian.org/releases/buster/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html#minimal-upgrade).

Comment: Should I always restart with `sudo reboot` after it?

Comment: I needed to add **-y** for it to work. Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: @hellboy No need to every time. It will usually inform you if a reboot is required.

Comment: Just pointing out that `apt full-upgrade` performs the same function as `apt-get dist-upgrade`, if, like me, you're comparing the commands with other answers in this question.

Comment: @hellboy It will tell you if a reboot is required. Also it's unclear whether you're asking if rebooting command line is required - the answer is No. It doesn't matter how you restart the machine.

Comment: thank you for clarifying the difference between update upgrade and other commands.

Answer (score 163):

To install updates, Use:

```
sudo -s -- <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get full-upgrade -y
apt-get autoremove -y
apt-get autoclean -y
EOF
```

---

Or even shorter in a `for` loop (thanks @[dessert](https://askubuntu.com/users/507051/dessert)!):

```
sudo bash -c 'for i in update {,full-}upgrade auto{remove,clean}; do apt-get $i -y; done'
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the one-liner here @benny

Answer (score 100):

***This is normal behavior.***

The message you see on login has been appended to the server status 'Message-Of-The-Day', which is only **updated** each calendar day (or on server boot / startup).  Have a look at the contents, using

```
cat /etc/motd
```

Still seeing the same updates available, after running

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

is to be expected.  If you then re-run this command you will **only** be prompted for any further updates if even further (newer) updates have been released.

Comment: I'm noticing that any file changes in the whole system doesn't show until the next calendar day, is there a way for like "refresh" to start seeing changes right away?

Comment: Do you mean updates for the content of **Message-Of-The-Day**, or not getting what you want after running **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`** ?

Comment: This is no longer true on 16.04. After "apt-get dist-upgrade" and a reboot I see "0 packages can be upgraded".

Comment: The **'.. or on server reboot ..'** statement above does cover that.

Comment: cat: /etc/motd: No such file or directory

Comment: This behaviour has clearly been changes, but needs more research ..

Comment: The last sentence of this answer makes no sense to me. "*...you will **only** be prompted for any further updates, even if further (newer) updates have been released.*" Should it perhaps read something like "*...you will not be prompted for any further updates, unless even newer ones have been released since you last ran the command.*"

Comment: Currently this gets updated without restarting.

Answer (score 13):

Once your log into your server, run the command below.

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It should do the trick. Maybe you just need to restart your server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I did try sudo apt-get upgrade. Restarting the server is out of the question because I have sites on it.

Comment: if you installed an update that directly affects the kernel or it's a driver update or it's a critical security update, you need to restart the server.

Comment: Maybe you should consider an error 503 for a minute. Do you know what kind of update this is ?

Comment: How can you give a 503 if the server is offline?

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I had an incorrect or not accessible [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) in **/etc/apt/sources.list.**
After removing this URL, I was able to update all packages successfully.

Commands:

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 8):

My (really late, I like necromancer badges :-) ) solution:

1. Install [wajig](http://www.togaware.com/linux/survivor/Wajig_Overview.html) (once):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wajig
   ```
2. When you want to update/upgrade fully your system

   ```
   wajig dailyupgrade
   ```

   (it will ask for password if needed, and do all the update, upgrade, dist-upgrade, and autoremove steps for you).

Answer (score 4):

You may also need to do this -

```
sudo touch /etc/motd.tail
```

From - [Ubuntu tells me I have packages to upgrade when I don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36517/ubuntu-tells-me-i-have-packages-to-upgrade-when-i-dont)

It worked for me on 14.04

Answer (score 1):

If you run `apt-get update` again after `apt-get upgrade` has been concluded, those messages at ssh login should go away.

Answer (score 0):

this script is handy to automate updates including removing unneeded packages and performing a reboot only if the OS wants one

```
remote_user=usernamehere
remote_host=example.com

ssh -A -n -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${remote_user}@${remote_host} && \
sudo apt-get update && \
sudo apt-get -f install -y && \
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" -yy dist-upgrade -y && \
sudo apt-get autoremove -y && \
[ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && \
echo "sudo reboot now" && \
sudo reboot now
```

to run on your local box just leave off that first line doing the ssh

here is an alias I save in ~/.bashrc

```
alias doit='echo; kill $( ps -eafww|grep update-manager|grep -v grep | grep update-manager | tr -s " " |cut -d" "  -f2 ) > /dev/null 2>&1;  echo "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&  [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && echo && echo reboot required && echo";echo;sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade &&  [ -f /var/run/reboot-required ] && echo && echo reboot required && echo '
```

then on terminal I just issue  `doit`