# Difficulties installing zoom_amd64.deb on a Dell XPS 9750 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dell, zoom-meeting

I've updated my Dell XPS 9750 with a fresh install of Ubunty 20.04 LTS (I had to resize the partitions as the Windows 10 partition needed more disc space).  Upon finishing the installation and updating of Ubuntu, I tried installing zoom_amd64.deb.  The following error was produced:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zoom:
 zoom depends on libgl1-mesa-glx; however:
  Package libgl1-mesa-glx is not installed.
 zoom depends on libegl1-mesa; however:
  Package libegl1-mesa is not installed.
 zoom depends on libxcb-xtest0; however:
  Package libxcb-xtest0 is not installed.
```

I then tried to update the individual packages specified herein.  However, each one of these packages has a long list of other packages that it is dependent upon.  So, I think my approach is incorrect.

Does anyone here have a way to get Zoom's video client to install and function correctly on a machine with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050Ti GPU, Nvidia's 450.57 proprietary drivers and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best tool to install deb packages](https://askubuntu.com/q/588170/)

Comment: @karel, I can give that a try.  I am wondering though, are the packages mentioned in the error components of another graphics driver?  Would Mesa and Nvidia's drivers be usable on the same at the same time?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesa_(computer_graphics)) says: *Proprietary graphics drivers (e.g., Nvidia GeForce driver and Catalyst) replace all of Mesa, providing their own implementation of a graphics API*, however it is OK to have both a proprietary graphics driver and an open source graphics driver installed alongside each other.

Comment: @karel, I'm now trying to follow your recommendations and I'm having difficulty actually doing so.  Do you have a guide that demonstrates how to install both drivers?  I've only be able to find processes to updating the mesa drivers on a laptop that does not have any proprietary drivers already installed.

Comment: This will install or reinstall the correct Nvidia proprietary graphics driver: https://askubuntu.com/a/1263215/