# Ubuntu 18.04 boots to black screen after trying to install proprietary Nvidia graphics driver

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, software-installation

At first, I was facing too big display problem to fix this I ran these commands as I was found this as a solution in a link.

`sudo apt-get update && clear && apt-cache search nvidia-[0-9] | grep 'binary driver'`

`sudo apt-get purge nvidia*`

`sudo apt-get install nvidia-340 nvidia-settings`

`sudo nvidia-xconfig`

After rebooting!! I am facing a black screen problem!

Please find the video on this link ([link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BYokRUAUaXxqSz187t1obtfXepuhaXI3/view?usp=sharing))

How to fix this problem, I tried setting nomodeset but no joy.

Comment: Your problem may be related to this:https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it.

Comment: @Freax In this case when we know the cause of the black screen it's not appropriate to select the broadest possible generic question instead of using the information that we already have.

Comment: @Freax thank you! I tried with that before. It did not work out.

Comment: @Freax As it turns out my answer solved the problem, and it's not a duplicate of the link that you posted in your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the built-in ubuntu-drivers program decide automatically which proprietary graphics drivers to install. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove '^nvidia'
sudo apt autoremove
sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot
```

The install option of ubuntu-drivers installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies.

Comment: thank you for your quick response! I removed Nvidia successfully! but apt update throwing E: failed to fetch  link error and could not resolve archive.ubuntu.com problem

Comment: That's a package management error. Please run `sudo apt update` and copy/paste the entire block of error messages into your question. I suspect there is a bad PPA line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` that needs to be commented out by preceding it with a `#` character and then try to run `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I just tried to reboot the computer after autoremove. The black screen problem is solved!! It is back to a big display.

Comment: Sure!! I will do it!! Thank you so much for your great help! Now the big problem is solved!! Next, I will try to fix the big screen issue!!

Comment: The first step to solving the big screen issue is to run `xrandr` command and this will show what your available display resolution options are. xrandr is used to set the size, orientation and/or reflection of the outputs for a screen. It can also set the screen size. For more information run `man xrandr`.

Comment: That's great!! Thank you. I will try this out Karel!

Comment: Karel! You solution "sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot" is solved big screen problem too! Thanks a lot!!