# Pacman's equivalent in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, package-management

I use [`pacman`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman) in Arch Linux for installing packages.

- The command for installing is `pacman -S`,
- The command for a full system upgrade is `pacman -Syu` and
- The command for repository update is `pacman -Syy`.

I want to know what is the equivalent for `pacman` in Ubuntu and its corresponding command.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/196768/how-to-install-updates-via-command-line

Comment: Install https://github.com/icy/pacapt and you can use the commands you're used to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I have to refer you to this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) from Arch Wiki which compares pacman commands with other package managers:

```
Arch            Debian/Ubuntu
```

```
pacman -[S|Q]i  apt show / apt-cache policy
pacman -Qi      dpkg -s / aptitude show
pacman -Si      apt-cache show / aptitude show
pacman -Ql      dpkg -L
pacman -Fl      apt-file list $pattern
pacman -Qo      dpkg -S / dlocate
pacman -Ql      dpkg-query -L
pacman -Fo      apt-file search
pacman -Fs      apt-file search
pacman -Qc      apt-get changelog

pacman -Ss      apt search
pacman -Qu      apt-get upgrade -> n
pacman -Sl      apt-cache dumpavail
...
...
```

A shot from page:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is Debian based Linux distro.
It uses the [APT](https://wiki.debian.org/Apt) for package management.

#### Command for updating the repositories

```
sudo apt-get update
```

#### Command for updating the system packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

#### Command for installation of package

```
sudo apt-get install <package_name>
```

Comment: This Answer should probably be reordered a bit since `apt-get update` should always be the very first command to run.

Comment: `apt` should be used instead of `apt-get`, the manpage says: *It is intended as an end user interface and enables some options better suited for interactive usage by default compared to more specialized APT tools like `apt-get`(8) and `apt-cache`(8).*

Comment: In the latest versions of Ubuntu, use `apt` instead of `apt-get`, e.g. `sudo apt update`. The newer command `apt` has been optimised in certain ways; see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/446484/2088).