# How to update to a specific version of Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates

I have an old PC which I installed Ubuntu on a long time ago that I want to update but not to the newest version of Ubuntu. I'm taking a programming class that requires me to use Ubuntu 14.04 for all my work and I would like to update this old box to that version.

`uname -a` returns this.

```
Linux ubuntu-Server 3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 3 21:30:07 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

14.04 is a supported version so I think this is possible. I've tried to look it up with `man apt-get` but didn't see anything about specific versions.

I'd really like to not have to wipe out everything I have on there and reinstall from disk.

Thanks.

Edit:

Turns out I had an old version of 14.04 already installed so using the following commands updated everything and I'm good to go.

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
```

Commands from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/196777/245545)

Comment: As long as your computer can boot from USB or DVD simply create a Ubuntu 14.04 boot installation media: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix will that accomplish a non destructive update? So my existing data will be interact?

Comment: Definitely destructive. My apologies I was reading too fast and saw "wipe out everything" without the prefixing qualifier. You want to upgrade an earlier version of Ubuntu Server to Ubuntu Server 14.04 then? What is the output of `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: In addition to upgrading from unsupported release you can install Ubuntu desktop 14.04 on top of your Server edition: https://askubuntu.com/questions/322122/switching-from-server-to-desktop

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Apparently I am running 14.04 (According to you command). but it's version 14.04.1 LTS. How do I update it to 14.04.5 LTS or what ever is the latest version of 14.04?

Comment: To get to newest 14.04, you need the enablement stack. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_-_Trusty_Tahr