# Error whilst executing Netgen 5.3.1 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, make, error-handling, mesh

Can anyone help solve the runtime error for Netgen 5.3.1. [NETGEN](https://sourceforge.net/projects/netgen-mesher/) is an automatic 3d tetrahedral mesh generator. The error message is:

```
:/opt/netgen/bin$ ./netgen
NETGEN-5.3.1
Developed by Joachim Schoeberl at
2010-xxxx Vienna University of Technology
2006-2010 RWTH Aachen University
1996-2006 Johannes Kepler University Linz
optfile ./ng.opt does not exist - using default values
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  558
  Current serial number in output stream:  559
```

Instructions on installing netgen-5.3.1 are given [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/netgen-mesher/wiki/Home/).

The software seems to have followed `./configure` , `make` and `sudo make install` correctly.

I followed the instructions from a [web page](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=782361) with a similar error message, but it did not resolve the problem. I.e. installing `Togl-1.7` .

The end output of `sudo make install` gave:

```
libtool: relink: g++  -fPIC -DPIC -shared -nostdlib /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtbeginS.o  .libs/nglib.o   -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/opt/netgen/lib -L/opt/netgen/lib -linterface -lgeom2d -lcsg -lstl -locc -lmesh -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../.. -lstdc++ -lm -lgomp -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o  -O2 -fopenmp   -fopenmp -Wl,-soname -Wl,libnglib.so -o .libs/libnglib.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnglib.soT /opt/netgen/lib/libnglib.so
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libnglib.lai /opt/netgen/lib/libnglib.la
libtool: finish: PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /opt/netgen/lib
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Libraries have been installed in:
   /opt/netgen/lib

If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
specify the full pathname of the library, or use the `-LLIBDIR'
flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
     during execution
   - add LIBDIR to the `LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
     during linking
   - use the `-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
   - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to `/etc/ld.so.conf'

See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
test -z "/opt/netgen/bin" || /bin/mkdir -p "/opt/netgen/bin"
  /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c ng_vol ng_stl '/opt/netgen/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/ng_vol /opt/netgen/bin/ng_vol
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/ng_stl /opt/netgen/bin/ng_stl
test -z "/opt/netgen/share/netgen" || /bin/mkdir -p "/opt/netgen/share/netgen"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 cube.surf '/opt/netgen/share/netgen'
test -z "/opt/netgen/include" || /bin/mkdir -p "/opt/netgen/include"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 nglib.h '/opt/netgen/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1/nglib'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1/nglib'
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/brendan/Documents/hpfem-mpt/netgen-5.3.1'
```

Comment: Try ```LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' ./netgen ```

Comment: I tried this, adding it to ~/.profile as:  `export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' ./netgen` ---- however it gives the same error.

Comment: One option could be to follow the example of  hangkongwang @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/893922/ubuntu-16-04-gives-x-error-of-failed-request-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-o ---- who has a similar error message. Not sure how to do that? I'll try it out.

Comment: I got the same with `netgen` version 4.9.13 from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/netgen) (Intel built-in video). But it works on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a known [bug 1556445](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netgen/+bug/1556445).

If you use version 4.9.13 from official repository (installed with `sudo apt-get install netgen`) you can "patch" it by running the following command manually:

```
sudo sed -i "s/\-indirect\ true\ \}/\-indirect\ false\ \}/g" \
/usr/share/netgen/drawing.tcl
```

This method came from [Netgen SourceForge Maillist](https://sourceforge.net/p/netgen-mesher/discussion/905307/thread/946ccfc2/#8e17):

> Joachim Schoeberl - 2016-02-04
>
> edit file ng/drawing.tcl line 14:
>
> `if {[catch {togl .ndraw -width 400 -height 300 -rgba true -double true -depth true -privatecmap false -stereo false -indirect true }] } { ....`
>
> change "`-indirect true`" to "`-indirect false`"
>
> Joachim

May work with manually compiled version too (need changes in filepath - `/opt/netgen/bin/drawing.tcl`).

Answer (score 1):

I found I needed to follow my [previous method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1046577/make-error-while-installing-netgen-5-3-1-on-ubuntu-16-04/1046633#1046633), editing file `/opt/netgen/bin/drawing.tcl` at line 14

changing `-indirect true` to `-indirect false`

& executing at `/opt/netgen/bin` using `./netgen` was successful!

I found that executing it with `netgen &!` produced the same error message.

The error was that at `/opt/netgen/bin/drawing.tcl`:

```
# use this one for Togl 2.0
# if {[catch {togl .ndraw -width 400 -height 300  -rgba true -double true -depth true -privatecmap false -stereo false -indirect false -create init  -display draw -reshape reshape  }] } {    

if {[catch {togl .ndraw -width 400 -height 300  -rgba true -double true -depth true -privatecmap false -stereo false -indirect true }] } {    puts "no OpenGL" 
} {
```

I had altered the commented code at line 12 instead of line 14, as both lines look similar.

Comment: I did exactly the same but using `sed` - *stream editor for filtering and transforming text*. So I can't find differences between you solution and mine :)