# How Can I update and upgrade Ubuntu? My laptop comes with Ubuntu 18.04 and I want 18.04.3

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, updates

I bought my laptop Dell with Ubuntu and it comes with Ubuntu 18.04. How can I update and upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04.3?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. It is automatic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install updates via command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196768/how-to-install-updates-via-command-line).  You can also use the Software Center (GUI package manager)

Comment: Go to system settings, click on software and updates, click on updates and check your settings.  Should be daily or weekly, and you are good.

Comment: The factory version is totally obsolete. The kernel, for example, is 4.15. After I installed for the first time, I did update and upgrade from terminal, but a error happened after restarted my laptop. Just the Ubuntu's background appeared. I couldn't login.

Comment: Your machine will upgrade to 18.04.x automatically if you `sudo apt full-upgrade` or grab all system updates normally. When Ubuntu 20.04.1 is released you'll be offered the choice of moving to 20.04, but as long as you install updates when offered, you'll automatically upgrade from 18.04 to .1, .2, .3, .4, .5 as they become available.  4.15 is the 18.04 kernel unless HWE is enabled.  Your last comment is also asking about HWE kernels, but your question doesn't mention that (HWE kernels are only default for 18.04.2 & later installs, need to be enabled for 18.04 & 18.04.1 installs)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has the 4.15 kernel by default, it's the stable option. HWE allows 18.04 LTS to use 18.10's, 19.04's, and in the future 19.10's and finally 20.04 LTS's kernel which can be beneficial for later hardware at a very minor (potential) loss of stability (it's been tested in production far less) by enabling HWE or hardware enablement stack kernel - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack All security fixes are backported to 4.15 which is deemed the most stable for 18.04 (if this changes, notices will come out, eg 14.04 users were advised to shift to HWE late in it's life)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are point releases in LTS versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106159/what-are-point-releases-in-lts-versions)

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to update is

`alt + ctrl + t` to open a terminal emulator

> sudo apt update

To fetch the database

> sudo apt upgrade

To make the actual install

If you want to upgrade to the next version of the system, then the command is

> do-release-upgrade

Comment: If I use do-release-upgrade, will the Kernel upgrade too?

Comment: Everything will be made to jump to the next version, so if it uses a newer kernel it will get it and install it. If you allready have that kernel it will leave it alone.