# /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check returns wrong information; also affects motd

Tags: 12.04, updates, package-management, motd

My question is related to [Ubuntu tells me I have packages to upgrade when I don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36517/ubuntu-tells-me-i-have-packages-to-upgrade-when-i-dont), which pertains to Ubuntu 10.04. But my problem is with Ubuntu 12.04.2LTS (and the solutions mentioned for 10.04 do not work).

Based on what I learned from that question, and related questions on ServerFault (also with unhelpful answers), I have tried running `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check --human-readable`, but it returns wrong information (the same information which gets added automatically to `/etc/motd` and displayed at every login via ssh):

```
6 packages can be updated.
6 updates are security updates.
```

Just today I ran `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and there was one regular update available (plus 3 kernel packages, which were held back). But my update and upgrade did not change the output of `apt-check`. I have been having this problem for a while and just decided to look into it today.

For 10.04, I have seen fixes related to `/etc/motd.tail`, but no such file exists on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out the `apt-check` message was correct. But the `apt-get upgrade` message was misleading. It said:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-headers-server linux-image-server linux-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

This naturally leads one to believe that there are only 3 packages which could potentially be downloaded and installed/upgrade.

But when I did `sudo apt-get install linux-server` (the only way I know to get past the 'kept back' status on upgrade), it said:
`3 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

That's right, 3 + 3 = 6 packages, just like `apt-check` said! And after the install/upgrade, a fresh login shows no available updates.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the package cache and download it again:

`sudo dpkg --clear-avail`

`sudo apt-get update`

If it doesn't solve the problem, create an empty `motd.tail`:

`sudo touch /etc/motd.tail`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but I figured it out. Nothing was broken; it was just a case of confusing/misleading messages.